# Trying to compare non-ordered queryset against more than one ordered values django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-queryset

This unit test fails with the following exception:

```
def test_vote_form_with_multiple_choices_allowed_and_submitted(self):
    """
    If multiple choices are allowed and submitted, the form should be valid.
    """
    vote_form = VoteForm({'choice': [1, 2]}, instance=create_question('Dummy question', -1,
                                                                      [Choice(choice_text='First choice'), Choice(
                                                                          choice_text='Second choice')],
                                                                      allow_multiple_choices=True))
    self.assertTrue(vote_form.is_valid())
    self.assertQuerysetEqual(vote_form.cleaned_data['choice'], ['<Choice: First choice>', '<Choice: Second choice>'])
```

> ValueError: Trying to compare non-ordered queryset against more than one ordered values

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.assertQuerysetEqual):

> By default, the comparison is also ordering dependent. If qs doesn’t provide an implicit ordering, you can set the ordered parameter to False, which turns the comparison into a collections.Counter comparison. If the order is undefined (if the given qs isn’t ordered and the comparison is against more than one ordered values), a ValueError is raised.

You are comparing a `QuerySet` with a `list`. List has an ordering but Queryset doesn't.

So you can either convert QuerySet to list

```
queryset = vote_form.cleaned_data['choice']
self.assertQuerysetEqual(list(queryset), ['<Choice: First choice>', ...])
```

or pass `ordered=False` to `assertQuerysetEqual`.

```
queryset = vote_form.cleaned_data['choice']
self.assertQuerysetEqual(list(queryset), ['<Choice: First choice>', ...], ordered=False)
```

Reordering Queryset before comparing should also work.